# Special Characters not supported by AWS Polly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-polly

We are using AWS polly service for text-to-speech. We are using text type as SSML. But we found that there are some characters which AWS Polly not supports in the text which we want to convert. For example character '&' is not supported.

Can I get list of characters which are not supported by Polly. If anyone knowing this will be really helpful for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Char not supported in SSML are on left side in Table of attached Image.

[image]